# How to get the date of today -30 / -60 days?

Tags: mysql

For example, i want get the data on exact date of today before 60 days.

I have tried the follow query but it select all the records from 60 days ago until today.

```
(bill_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

What i want is the records on 60 days ago. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean records on or before 60 days ago?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `=` instead of `>`!

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE bill_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY);
```

**today + 60 days (only this day) using [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE bill_date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY);
```

**today - 60 days (only this day) using [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE bill_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY);
```

**all records between now and -/+ 60 days:**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE bill_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW();

SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE bill_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Comment: As per my understanding, Query first given in this answer will do the trick and get data of that day as you need

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question. Try this query. And please do more clear your question.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE bill_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW();
```